# Getting default icon background with custom status bar notifications

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm currently creating a custom status bar notification to notify the user of progress through an event. I have the custom notification working fine, but having a progress bar requires that I pass my own set of RemoteViews to the notification through the contentView field.

This is fine, except that I want to be able to base this layout off the default one. I am targeting API 10, and so it must work with both Gingerbread and ICS. Gingerbread is fine, as I can just put an icon on the left of the layout and the notification fits in with other default ones. In ICS however, the notification icons all have the striped square on the left that contains the icon (it effectively forms a UI "handle" to help indicate that the notification can be swiped to dismiss it).

Does anyone know how I can either get the default layout in code, and then edit it (this is hard with remoteViews), or somehow get access to default layout view (probably during runtime), then copy it, and substitute the notification text for my progress bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have seen examples where people have created a notification and cloned the layout, but to do anything useful with that you have to know quite a lot about the layout. I would rather get the layout files from the android versions you are interested in. [Here](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/notification_template_base.xml) you have the JB one, you should not have any problems finding the others.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Having API version specific code was my fallback, and it looks like thats what i'm going to have to do. It has to possible though, google apps (play and browser downloads, etc) do it somehow.

Comment: As I said, I'm quite sure that I have seen examples of extracting the layout, but you still have to know the layout to replace a component. Right? What makes you think that they don't use platform specific layouts? That is what they do for action bar icons/menu icons, and status bar icons.

Answer (score 0):

If the only reason you want a custom layout is to get a progress bar, you could look at
 [NotificationCompat.Builder.setProgress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html#setProgress%28int,%20int,%20boolean%29). It'll be easier than playing with custom notification layouts. If you do decide to use custom layouts, they changed only slightly between API v14 and API v17, and I have no idea what they're like for Honeycomb but they're unlikely to be much different. What that means is that you should be able to use one custom notification layout in a layout-v11 folder, and one in your default layout folder, and you'll catch most cases (except for the icon background from Honeycomb upwards, I haven't gotten that part working in my own custom notifications yet) and only have to maintain two different layouts. See the answer above for the location of the default layout; note that it's called status_bar_latest_event_content.xml in earlier versions of Android.

Since setProgress() is available from Honeycomb upwards at least, and it looks like it works on earlier versions too (the docs don't say otherwise), then you should probably use that if you don't have any other custom requirements.